# Access PHP Require variables with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my project layout:

Page.php requires Master.php which has some variables like $uid,$uname, etc.

So, Page.php is able to access these variables which is what I want.

Now, Page.php has a button which when clicked loads Subpage.php in a container using AJAX (JQuery).

Now, the problem is Subpage.php is not able to access the variables $uid,$uname, etc.

I know I can pass it as parameters using get or post while doing the AJAX request.. But is there any way in which I can allow Subpage.php access all variables from Master.php when called via AJAX?

Thanks in advance.

PS: There are more subpages, so I dont have the option to require the Subpage also in PHP

Comment: When you call a php page with ajax you get the executed result. If you want to access those variables you may echo them as a javascript object, but you have other options too.

Comment: @DimitrisKontoulis: Yes bro. Its other way round.. I dont want the variables from the AJAXed page.. I want the AJAXed page to be able to access the variables of the page which is sending the request to it (without having the requirement of parameters)

Comment: @PedroLobito: Its too big.. Almost 300 lines.. So, useless posting it cause noone would understand.. I just need the logic..

Comment: So, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: @PedroLobito: Bro, I just need the logic.. Like how do I access variables of a php page from within a new PHP page which is loaded via AJAX. Thats all..

Comment: I think you have answer now, from Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using global session variables? 
This way you will be able to access to the needed data

Comment: k.. will do that.. It will be a bit too painstaking to modify all variables to session variables but I think that will do. Thanks.